# master_not_discovered_exception ElasticSearch single node

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to setup elasticsearch on a single host. Here is how my configuration looks like:

**elasticsearch.yml**

```
node.name: ${HOSTNAME}

network.host: _site_, _local_
http.port: 9200
transport.tcp.port: 9300
cluster.name: "test_cluster"
node.local: true
```

**kibana.yml**

```
server.host: 0.0.0.0
elasticsearch.url: http://localhost:9200
```

On following command:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty'
```

I get following message:

```
{
  "error" : {
  "root_cause" : [
   {
      "type" : "master_not_discovered_exception",
      "reason" : null
   }
  ],
  "type" : "master_not_discovered_exception",
  "reason" : null
},
 "status" : 503
}
```

In log file I see following message:

```
not enough master nodes discovered during pinging (found [[]], but needed [-1]), pinging again
```

Could someone please point me right direction here?

Answer (score 33):

I spent days (sigh) on basically this. I was trying to upgrade my single node cluster from 6.x es to 7.x, and I kept dying on the hill of "master_not_discovered_exception".

What finally solved it for me was examining a completely fresh install of 7.x.

For my single-node cluster, my */etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml* needed the line:

```
discovery.type: single-node
```

I hope that saves someone else from spending days like I did. In my defence, I'm very new to es.

Comment: Thank you, this also solved the issue for me. It seems like even with a fresh install of ES7+, this settings is not here.

Comment: @JulienLeCoupanec - weird you didn't see it even in a fresh 7.x install. Maybe they changed the defaults? Regardless, I'm glad this answer post helped save you some time!

Answer (score 4):

Following changes in `eleasticsearch.yml` worked for me

**Node**

```
node.name: node-1
```

**Paths**

```
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch

path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
```

**Network**

```
network.host: 0.0.0.0

http.port: 9200
```

**Discovery**

```
discovery.seed_hosts: "127.0.0.1:9300"

cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-1"]
```

**Steps:**

1. `sudo systemctl stop elasticsearch.service`
2. `sudo nano /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml`
3. `Apply above changes, save and close the editor.`
4. `sudo /bin/systemctl daemon-reload`
5. `sudo /bin/systemctl enable elasticsearch.service`
6. `sudo systemctl start elasticsearch.service`

***NOTE:*** ***elasticsearch7 is used with ubuntu 20.04, it should work with other versions as well***

Comment: on `Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS` worked for me

Answer (score 1):

According to this [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/discovery-settings.html#initial_master_nodes), for the very first time you should set `initial_master_nodes` config like this in `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml`:

```
node.name: "salehnode"

cluster.initial_master_nodes: 
   - salehnode
```

Answer (score 1):

On my side, after installing ES 7+, I had to set node-1 as a master-eligible node in the new cluster.

> sudo nano /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml

```
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-1"]
```

Answer (score 0):

First I dont think you need `network.host` setting for this.

In your log it is trying to get a master, but result is 0

Can you try setting properties like:

```
node.master: true
node.data:true
```

Also can you please put more logs here, if it doesnt work

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Nikunj! Still not working. This is all I see in logs:

[2017-07-23T13:00:25,440][WARN ][o.e.d.z.ZenDiscovery     ] [] not enough master nodes discovered during pinging (found [[]], but needed [-1]), pinging again

Comment: By any chance can you put here any other entry you have im yml file. Because error is coming from ZenDiscovery, why should that be enabled for single node?

Comment: That's all the config I have. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your `elasticsearch.yml`:

```
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 1
```

I think `ES` will always find `discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts` until it 
finds `nodes` of `count` equal to `minimum_master_nodes`.